# Enhanced For Loops - Java

Tags: java

I am trying to use a method for an object in an array in an enhanced for loop but it gives me an error message that says null. Here is my code:

```
Pet[] pets = new Pet[10];

pets[0] = new Pet("Buddy", 2);
pets[1] = new Pet("Cocoa", 2);
pets[2] = new Pet("Caramel", 1);
pets[3] = new Pet("Oreo", 1);

for (Pet p : pets)
{
  p.feed();
}
```

Comment: `pets[4]` to `pets[9]` are null because you haven't set them to anything.

Comment: what should I do? Is there anything AI can do besides initialize them

Comment: Either make your array smaller so it doesn't contain null elements; or change to `if (p!=null)  { p.feed(); }`.

Comment: Or better yet, use an `ArrayList<Pet>`